# How to create an ImageView as drag and drop?

Tags: applescript-objc

I would like to know how to make an ImageView drag and drop,
I will drag a certain file to an ImageView and it will render
an action.

I know I can use the code below in a Script Editor and save it as a
application could then drag the files into it and do an action but would like to
know how it would be done in an ImageView.

Thanks in advance!

```
on open myItems
    repeat with one_item in myItems
        ---Blablabla        
    end repeat
end open
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An **NSImageView**'s parent class is [NSControl](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscontrol?language=objc), so like any other control it has a target/action you can specify, for example:

```
use AppleScript version "2.4" -- Yosemite (10.10) or later
use framework "Foundation"
use scripting additions

property mainWindow : missing value

on run -- Script Editor example
    my performSelectorOnMainThread:"doWindowStuff" withObject:(missing value) waitUntilDone:true
end run

on doWindowStuff() -- window stuff needs to be done on the main thread
    try
        set my mainWindow to makeWindow out of {{0, 0}, {400, 200}} given title:"Drag an image:"
        set imageView to makeImageView out of {{100, 50}, {200, 100}}
        mainWindow's contentView's addSubview:imageView
        mainWindow's makeKeyAndOrderFront:me
    on error errmess
        display alert "Error" message errmess
    end try
end doWindowStuff

to makeWindow out of frame given title:title : "" -- make and return a window
    tell (current application's NSWindow's alloc()'s initWithContentRect:frame styleMask:7 backing:2 defer:yes) -- styleMask of 7 includes title, close and minimize buttons
        if first item of frame is {0, 0} then tell it to |center|()
        its setAutorecalculatesKeyViewLoop:true
        its setTitle:title
        return it
    end tell
end makeWindow

to makeImageView out of frame -- make and return an image view
    tell (current application's NSImageView's alloc()'s initWithFrame:frame)
        its setTarget:me
        its setAction:"imageDragged:"
        its setEditable:true
        its setImageScaling:(current application's NSImageScaleProportionallyUpOrDown)
        return it
    end tell
end makeImageView

on imageDragged:sender
    activate me
    display dialog "An image was dragged into the image view."
end imageDragged:
```

To do something like get the file path for a dropped image, **NSImageView** will need to be subclassed.  For an Xcode project, add a new `.applescript` file for the subclass, and set it as the class of your imageView in IB's Identity Inspector:

```
script MyImageView -- NSImageView subclass

    property parent : class "NSImageView"
    property imagePath : missing value

    on draggingEntered:sender
        # additional stuff as desired
        return current application's NSDragOperationCopy
    end draggingEntered:

    on performDragOperation:sender
        set pasteboard to sender's draggingPasteboard()
        set theOptions to {NSPasteboardURLReadingFileURLsOnlyKey:1}
        set imageURLs to pasteboard's readObjectsForClasses:{current application's |NSURL|} options:theOptions
        set draggedURL to first item of (imageURLs as list)
        set my imagePath to draggedURL as text
        return true -- data accepted
    end performDragOperation:

end script
```

You should also register the acceptable drag type(s) for your imageView somewhere in the AppDelegate's setup:

```
imageView's registerForDraggedTypes:{"public.image"}
```

The file path will then be available in the imageView's `imagePath` property when you drag something to the view. See Apple's [Drag and Drop Programming Topics](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DragandDrop/DragandDrop.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000069-SW1) for more information.